# Not all empty lists are removed from ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I have code to create a grouped list for a ListView in Xamarin Forms, which for some reason only *sometimes* removes a group from the list if it is empty.

```
char[] alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
var animals = new List<string>() { "Jaguar", "Elephant", "Nemo", "Cat", "Dog", "Iguana", "Puma", "Crow", "Hawk", "Owl", "Badger", "Meerkat", "Lion", "Tiger", "Rabbit", "Pig" };

var groups = new ObservableCollection<GroupedItemModel>();

for (int i = 0; i < alpha.Length; i++)
{
    groups.Add(new GroupedItemModel(alpha[i].ToString()));
}

foreach (var _group in groups)
{
    foreach (var _animal in animals)
    {
        if (_animal[0].ToString().ToUpper() == _group.GroupName.ToUpper())
        {
            _group.Add(_animal);
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count; i++)
{
    if (groups[i].Count == 0)
    {
        groups.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}

ListSource = groups;
```

However, this happens:

[image: Image of listview]

Why do these groups not get removed? Any solutions?

Comment: You sure you are not initializing an empty list. Maybe it removes nulls but not empty lists. Just a guess though.

Comment: modifying a collection as you're iterating through it usually doesn't work the way you expect.  A better approach would be to iterate once and make a new list of the items to be removed; after you complete the iteration, then delete the items all at once

Answer (score 2):

When removing from a list you need to work backwards.

such as:

if you have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and you say remove even numbers as its 1-10, 
on 1 thats ok, on 2, you remove it, so 3 moves into its place.. so now you arent checking 3...you skip to 4.. so in this example you'd get away withit, but what if your list was already missing say 3, it would have moved number 4 to the place where 2 had been, and move on, 4 would be missed

Change your for loop to be decremental

Answer (score 1):

As described by BugFinder above, the problem you are getting is caused by modifying the list as you iterate through it. Problem solved. But it might also be worth taking a look at the overall approach.  Currently we:

1. Create list of all possible groups (A-Z)
2. Iterate though the list of animals and add each to a group based upon the first letter
3. Iterate though the groups and throw away any which are empty.

This can all be done with a few lines of Linq code and a tweak to the `GroupedItemModel`

```
public class GroupedItemModel
{
    public GroupedItemModel(string name, IEnumerable<string> values){
        Name = name;
        Values =  new List<string>(values);
    }

    public string Name { get;  }
    public List<string> Values { get;  }

}
```

We can now populate an `ObservableCollection<GroupedItem>` with

```
new ObservableCollection<GroupedItem>(animals.GroupBy(a => char.ToUpper(a[0]).ToString()).OrderBy(g => g.Key).Select(g => new GroupedItem(g.Key, g)));
```

Very minor afterword: Prefixing variable names with underscores is usually used for member variables of a class, not for local variables (_group, _animal). It doesn't change how the code works but when sharing code with others, using the general conventions helps speed up reading and understanding the code.